# How to setup the git user of Jenkins slave agents

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've a jenkins multibranch pipeline jobs with the following checkout step:

```
    stage('Checkout'){
        steps{
            echo "Custom checkout: ${env.BRANCH_NAME} on ${pwd()}"
            checkout scm
        }
    }
```

When I run it on my master, everything is going fine. It uses the credentials from my credentials manager.

But if it gets executed by the slave, not sure why, but I get this error:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --no-tags --progress https://my.bitbucket/scm/Project/repository.git +refs/heads/feature/jenkins-build-with-custom-id:refs/remotes/origin/feature/jenkins-build-with-custom-id" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://my.bitbucket/scm/Project/repository.git/'
```

I was thinking that this should uses the same username-password than the one I set on git repository, no? What is wrong? How should I configure this?

if I do a `git clone https://my.bitbucket/scm/Project/repository.git/` I've the same issue. If I specify my user manually `git clone https://jenkins@my.bitbucket/scm/Project/repository.git/` it works, but I don't see how I can configure

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Comment: @user3159253 And what do I do with it? I've tried to do `git config --global credential.helper store` but I still have Authentication failed, no prompt

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the credentials plugin.
Create a new credential for your bitbucket user and the add it to you git checkout

```
git(
   url: 'https://my.bitbucket/scm/Project/repository.git',
   credentialsId: 'my-bitbucket-user-credential',
   branch: "${branch}"
)
```

Or use the credential on your job configuration when using multi branch jobs. Anyway, the credential plugin is the way to go. Don't try to use git specific methods like the credential helper as this will not work between slaves and master nodes